# Pie Chart using CSS3

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a symmetrical pie-chart with 6 pieces of 60 degrees each using html and CSS3 (only).

I've come across this article http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2011/how-to-create-pie-charts-with-css3/ but doesn't quite understand the concept.

Can anyone help me with it **or** explain what is `.pieSliceBlue`, `.hold` and `.pie` classes in the link above responsible for?

Comment: Actually that very article has a link to http://atomicnoggin.ca/blog/2010/02/20/pure-css3-pie-charts/ which explains how the writer got his chart.

Comment: Ooops. I seem to have missed it. My mistake.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280127/css-pie-charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.elated.com/articles/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/

It is far more easier to use this JQuery and CSS, just need to give the values and pie chart will be created automatically.